# Cannot initialize a class, no matter where I try

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm unable to initialize my sampleList List class, no matter where I try it, I always get

**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class AudioSamples
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public AudioClip audioClip { get; set; }

}

public class AudioDB
{
    public List<AudioSamples> sampleList;

    public AudioDB()
    {
        this.sampleList = new List<AudioSamples>();
    }
}
```

Even when I try it implicitly like this, after initializing the AudioDBinstance, the sampleList is never initialized.

```
AudioDBinstance[x].sampleList = new List<AudioSamples>();
```

I tried everything and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: Just to clarify, I initialize the AudioDB class as array

```
AudioDBinstance = new AudioDB[Count];
```

SOLVED:

Turns out I wasn't initializing the instances in the array.

```
AudioDBinstance[x] = new AudioDB();
```

This extra line solved it.
Thank you @LarsTech

Comment: as longf as you did AudioDB somevar = new AudioDb().. from that your somevar.sampleList should be empty but initliased.. where are you initialising it?

Comment: I just added a clarification. I declare AudioDB[] AudioDBinstance; as array, then initialize it with a count from another list: AudioDBinstance = new AudioDB[Count]; But even if I try to initialize AudioDBinstance[x].sampleList = new List<AudioSamples>(); right after, I get the NullReferenceException.

Comment: AH.. (im full of germs and not making code to check) but im confident you'll find its actually your AudioDBinstance[x] is whats null..

Comment: `AudioDBinstance = new AudioDB[Count]` does not initialize each audio item in the array.  Everything in that array is null at the moment.

Comment: How do I initialize it than?

Comment: `AudioDBinstance[x] = new AudioDB();`

Comment: Thank you! This one line of code changed everything. I spent literally hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: the fact that it was in my first comment?? sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AudioDBinstance = new AudioDB[Count];` will create array of default (initialized) instances and in case of [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) it will be filled with `null`'s. If you want array of actual instances then you will need to create them. One way here would be to use LINQ:

```
AudioDBinstance = Enumerable.Range(0, Count)
    .Select(_ => new AudioDB())
    .ToArray();
```

Or in your loop:

```
// no need to explicitly assign sampleList
// since it is done in AudioDB constructor
AudioDBinstance[x] = new AudioDB();
```

Comment: Thank you, already figured out, after @LarsTech's comment.